# Error message in new wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can someone help me?

I just downloaded and installed WordPress, then I installed the Rumba theme. I want to start working on the site but I keep getting this error message no matter what I try to save, and also when I just try to visit the site.

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/socialworkshop.dk/public_html/wp-content/themes/rambo/functions/woo/woocommerce.php:2) in /var/www/socialworkshop.dk/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1178

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write  on top of page `/var/www/socialworkshop.dk/public_html/wp-content/themes/rambo/functions/woo/woocommerce.php`

and on `/var/www/socialworkshop.dk/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php`